# QueuePool limit and timeout issue

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, connection-timeout

I tried to Best practice and base to my project for usage flask server. But SqlAlchemy give me this error:
" QueuePool limit size 20 overflow 0 reached, connection timed out,timed out 30<Background on this error at: [http://sqlalche.me/e/13/3o7r>](http://sqlalche.me/e/13/3o7r%3E)

how can figure out this issue ?
I editted app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] =100,  my sproblem is less repeated, but still couldnt fixed .
My app.py is:

```
connection_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(app.config['MSSQL_CONNECTION'])
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(connection_str)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = 20
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW'] = 0 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
```

Comment: always close connection and cursor in every view.

Comment: @harshilsuthar , how can I close it ?